# How to set individual bar plot's color

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to change the color of each individual bar in my figure here. The code that I used it down below. Instead of each bar changing to the color that I have set in c, there are several colors within each bar. I have included a screenshot of this. How can I fix this? Thank you all in advance!

Clusters is just a categorical variable of 5 groups, ranging from 0 to 4. I have included a second screenshot of the dataframe.

So essentially, what I am trying to do is to plot each cluster for economic ideology and social ideology so I can have a visual comparison of the 5 different clusters over these two dimensions (economic and social ideology). Each cluster should be represented by one color. For example, cluster 0 should be red in color.

```
c = ['#bf1111', '#1c4975', '#278f36', '#47167a', '#de8314']

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.bar(data = ANESdf_LatNEW, height = "EconIdeo", 
            x = "clusters", color = c)
plt.title('Economic Ideology')
plt.xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.xlabel('Clusters')
plt.ylabel('')



plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.bar(data = ANESdf_LatNEW, height = "SocialIdeo", 
            x = "clusters", color = c)
plt.title('Social Ideology')
plt.xticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.xlabel('Clusters')
plt.ylabel('')


plt.show()
```

[image: Bar graph here]

[image: Top 5 rows of dataframe]

I have tried multiple ways of changing colors. For example, instead of having c, I had put in the colors directly at color = ... This did not work either.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include the screenshot

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include a minimal example of what `ANESdf_LatNEW` is supposed to look like.  Assuming it's a dataframe, it would be particularly helpful if you could paste in the result of `ANESdf_LatNEW.head().to_dict()`.

Comment: At the very least, what does the "clusters" column look like?

Comment: You're giving the bar plot function the same x-value for the multiple y-values. It seems reasonable to me that the plot function is therefore plotting these bars on top of each other. If you want some **other** behavior (for instance, having the bars of multiple colors **next to** each other instead), then please edit your question to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: You might find [this pyplot demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html) to be useful.

Comment: Thank you Ben for the demo!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that does what you seem to be looking for based on your edits and comment.

Note that I do **not** assume that all clusters have the same size in this context; if that is the case, this approach can be simplified.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'EconIdeo':[1,2,3,4,3,5,7],
    'Clusters':[2,3,0,1,3,0,3]
})
print(df)

# parameters: width for each cluster, colors for each cluster
# (if clusters are not sequential from zero, replace c with dictionary)

width = .75
c = ['#bf1111', '#1c4975', '#278f36', '#47167a', '#de8314']

df['xpos'] = df['Clusters']
df['width'] = width
df['color'] = ''
clusters = df['Clusters'].unique()
for k in clusters:
    where = (df['Clusters'] == k)
    n = where.sum()
    df.loc[where,'xpos'] += np.linspace(-width/2,width/2,2*n+1)[1:-1:2]
    df.loc[where,'width'] /=n
    df.loc[where,'color'] = c[k]

plt.bar(data = df, height = "EconIdeo", x = 'xpos', 
        width = 'width', color = 'color')
plt.xticks(clusters,clusters)

plt.show()
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

Input dataframe:

```
       EconIdeo  Clusters
    0         1         2
    1         2         3
    2         3         0
    3         4         1
    4         3         3
    5         5         0
    6         7         3
```

Dataframe after script applies changes (to include plotting specifications)

```
       EconIdeo  Clusters    xpos  width    color
    0         1         2  2.0000  0.750  #278f36
    1         2         3  2.7500  0.250  #47167a
    2         3         0 -0.1875  0.375  #bf1111
    3         4         1  1.0000  0.750  #1c4975
    4         3         3  3.0000  0.250  #47167a
    5         5         0  0.1875  0.375  #bf1111
    6         7         3  3.2500  0.250  #47167a
```